# join performance, index vs. index+foreignkey

Tags: mysql, performance, join, foreign-key, query-performance

I'm using an orm framework that handles data (and its integrity) on top of mysql. So far I ignored foreign keys because the orm handles that just fine.
I recently read that foreign keys can enhance join-performance so I took the time two create a second schema where fks are added.

usually a join in the app/orm looks like this:

```
SELECT <fields...> FROM a
INNER JOIN b
ON a.property = b.pk
INNER JOIN c
ON a.property = c.pk
INNER JOIN d
ON c.property = d.pk
WHERE <something>
```

Each property that references a pk in another table always comes with an index but in the new additional schema an fk is also added (which, as i understand is formost a constraint).

Now I ran tests to measure the speed between schema a and b and could find no differences whatsoever. also whenever I use EXPLAIN on a statement it shows up exactly the same in both schemata.

am i missing something or is the conclusion valid that fks do in fact not enhance  select-performance if both property and pk in the join-condition are indexed anyway?

what could even be a possible advantage of the fk? the fact that the db knows that the value must exist?

is it true that mysql will attempt to put related data close together? and a foreign key will help mysql understand what is related?

Comment: Which version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: mysql version is 5.1.72